# How do I properly use peek(), or is there a better solution to read from a text file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use peek to make sure the file isn't empty, but it's not working. I'm using it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open(test.txt);

    if(file.peek() != '\n' && file.peek() != file.eof())
        cout << "fail" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

test.txt is just an empty text file. I expected my program not to go into the if statement because it is an empty file but instead it still goes in and prints fail. How do I properly use peek() here, or is there a better solution to this? Thanks

Comment: `file.eof()` doesn't do what you think it does. It returns a bool that is true if the stream has already tried to read past EOF, it does not return an EOF char, like you are expecting. `peek()` returns `std::char_traits::eof` on EOF. If the file is truly empty, there is no need to check for `'\n'`, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easy robust way to read lines from a text file.

```
std::ifstream file("test.txt");

for(std::string line; std::getline(file, line);)
{
//process line
}
```

Comment: @Raindrop7 - the advantage of the for loop is that the lifetime of `line` is limited to the for loop. Otherwise, I agree with you that a while loop may be easier to read for non-experts.

Comment: Yes. Finally I noticed that you created local variable in the loop. But  if not then `while` the choice.